# can I disable crouch on release of middle click?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I've been playing The Old Republic as a Bounty Hunter, but just started playing as a smuggler.

I can hold middle click to look around, and it changes my body orientation while moving. As a Bounty hunter releasing middle click allows me to keep moving in that direction. As a smuggler releasing middle click causes an auto crouch (or maybe it's Take cover, not sure).

Is there any way I can disable releasing middle click from auto crouching as the smuggler?

Answer (score 2):

It's under preferences -> keybindings (which is in a bottom row tab) -> targeting -> "take cover in place" and "take cover". simply click to set, then click unbind.